# Prove $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^nP(A_i \cap A_j) \geq \Bigl( \sum_{k=1}^n P(A_k) \Bigr)^2$

Tags: probability, inequality

Let $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ be positive events (meaning $P(A_k)>0)$. Show that:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^nP(A_i \cap A_j) \geq \Bigl( \sum_{k=1}^n P(A_k) \Bigr)^2$$

I tried doing some algebra but didn't get anything. Any ideas how to move forward?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Show that the left-hand side of the inequality equals $$\ell:=E \left[ \left( \sum_{j=1}^n 1_{A_j} \right)^2 \right]= E \left( \left| \sum_{j=1}^n 1_{A_j} \right|^2 \right).$$
2. Show that the right-hand side of the inequality equals $$r:=\left[ \mathbb{E} \left( \sum_{j=1}^n 1_{A_j} \right) \right]^2 = \left[ \mathbb{E} \left| \sum_{j=1}^n 1_{A_j} \right| \right]^2.$$
3. Apply Jensen's inequality (or the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality) to show that $\ell \geq r$.

Comment: Great solution. Is the absolute value needed though?

Comment: @user401516 Thanks, you are welcome. No, the absolute value is not really needed (since everything is non-negative);  I just thought that it makes things a little bit clearer because this way it is obvious that $$\ell = \|X\|_{L^2}^2 \quad \text{and} \quad r= \|X\|_{L^1}^2$$ for $X:= \sum_{j=1}^n 1_{A_j}$... therefore the assertion is a direct consequence of the (well-known) inequality $$\|X\|_{L^1} \leq \|X\|_{L^2}$$ (which is, in turn, a direct consequence of Jensen's inequality).

Answer (score 0):

Reformulation: Let $\chi_1, \ldots, \chi_n: \Omega \to \{0, 1\}$ be characteristic functions of measurable subsets of a probability space $\Omega$. Show that $$\int_\Omega (\chi_1(\omega) + \cdots + \chi_n(\omega))^2 d\omega \geq \left( \int_\Omega \chi_1(\omega) + \cdots + \chi_n(\omega) \right)^2.$$

Proof: Apply a corollary of the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality: for all real-valued functions $f$, $$\int_\Omega f^2(\omega)\, d\omega \geq \left( \int_\Omega f(\omega)\, d\omega\right)^2.$$